# Sklearn: How to apply dimensionality reduction on huge data set?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

**Problem:** OutOfMemory error is showing on applying the PCA on 8 million features.

Here is my code snipet:-

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=10000)
pca_tfidf_sklearn = sklearn_pca.fit(traindata_tfidf.toarray())
```

I want to apply the PCA / dimension reduction techniques on text extracted features (using tf-idf). Currently I am having around 8 million such feature and I want to reduce those features and to classify the documents I am using the MultiNomialNB.

And I am stucked due to the OutOfMemory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, `traindata_tfidf` is actually in a sparse form. Try using one of [scipy sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) formats instead of an array. Also take a look at [SparsePCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.SparsePCA.html) methods, and if it doesn't help, use [MiniBatchSparsePCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA.html).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I am implementing your suggestion. Moreover 10000 features out of 8 million is okay?

Comment: As always, it depends. There're several techniques of determining optimal number of PCs. Personally, I would start with somewhat small number like 50 and decide whether to increase it depending on overall model performance.

Comment: I tried with sparcepca<br />
from sklearn.decomposition import SparsePCA, MiniBatchSparsePCA
spca = SparsePCA(n_components=100, random_state=42)
newtfidf = spca.fit_transform(X_train_tfidf.todense())

but agian OutOfMemory error...
Anything wrong?
Ram 120GB & 24GB of free memory stilll.....

Comment: Probably, you shouldn't call `todense()`. What is the type of `X_train_tfidf`? Also check `RandomizedPCA`, it may be better with sparse formats.

Comment: PCA is O(n^3) (requires an SVD decomposition) I don't think it's the right tool for 8e6 features.

Comment: @cyberj0g **bold**type of tfidf:-**bold** scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix <br/>
`<400371x884997 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 23633967 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format> ` <br/>

Error log --> link [link](http://pastebin.com/jM0CuuF8) <br/>

And If I am not using the todense / toarray, Type error is showing as shown in this link [link](http://pastebin.com/zfiBhMTX) <br/>

MiniBatchSparsePCA is also failing due to conversion of it in dense. And I am stucked here due to this conversion.

Comment: Try `RandomizedPCA`, it's `fit_transform` method supports sparse data for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem. Using a Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM) instead of PCA fixed the problem. Mathematically, this is because PCA only looks at the EigenValues and EigenVectors of your feature matrix whereas RBM works as a neural network to consider all multiplicative possibilities of the features in your data. Therefore, RBM has a much greater set to consider when deciding which features are more important. It then reduces the quantity of features to a much smaller size with more important features than PCA can. However, be sure to Feature Scale and Normalize the data before applying an RBM to the data.